# Install Aleph on MacOS

Tags: macos, homebrew, yap

I'm trying to get ALEPH - A Learning Engine for Proposing Hypotheses - http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/activities/machinelearning/Aleph/aleph - on Mac.
As I understood, I will need YAP - Yet Another Prolog. As far as I've found on the internet everyone does it be "`brew install yap`" (I have brew). That's what I get:

```
$ brew install yap

Error: No available formula with the name "yap" 

==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...

Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:   git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...

==> Searching local taps...

Error: No similarly named formulae found.

==> Searching taps...

==> Searching taps on GitHub...

Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Does anyone have any idea of what to do?